# How to create a kite shaped surface

Tags: transform, famo.us

I am trying to build a surface with Famo.us that is shaped like a kite.

A kite is a quadrilateral whose four sides can be grouped into two pairs of equal-length sides that are adjacent to each other. I am looking to transform the rectangle of the shape of a surface into a kite shape. I can create parallelogram by skewX or skewY. A parallelogram also has two pairs of equal-length sides, but they are opposite each other rather than adjacent(like in a kite).

The surface is a div, and I want to change the shape from a surface from a square/rectangle into a kite. I trying to make a hex grid. I am surprised that a highly mathematical JavaScript Famo.us web platform does not have a Triangular surface. I like a Famo.us only solution, it possible.

Comment: Now that it has been put on hold. I read deeper into your question and am wondering if you meant you wanted to go from a square to a kite shape using a transform. Did you mean it differently than I answered?

Comment: Yes, I do want to transform a square/rectangle into a kite.

Comment: You will need to do it with a canvas.  Famo.us can only transition what normal css tranfrorms can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is valid, but there is a caveat. A surface (`div`) of this shape requires us to create a two part style using `after`.  Your use case may limit the use of this solution.

**Without Famo.us:** Using a div and css you can create a kite shape.

[image]

```html
<div class="kite-css"></div>
```

```css
.kite-css {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 50px solid red;
  top: -40px;
  position: relative;
}
.kite-css:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: -50px; 
  top: 50px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 50px solid transparent;
  border-top: 90px solid red;
  z-index: -1
}
```

**Using Famo.us:** Use some modified css from above and adding the class to the Famo.us surface. I added some `background-color` of the `Surface` to highlight the surface area that will be used for rendering size. I added some text in the content of the surface to show how text is affected by this method.

[image]
**Issues:**

- The true center of the surface is the center of the shaded area in the image above. This is the `element` created by Famo.us and the lower piece is created by the style using `after`.
- The usable content starts at the center of the top piece, because the border squeezes out all sides of the square.

```css
.kite-shape {
  border: 50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 50px solid red;
  top: -40px;
}
.kite-shape:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: -50px; 
  top: 50px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 50px solid transparent;
  border-top: 90px solid red;
  z-index: -1
}
```

```js
  var kite = new Surface({ 
    size: [100, 100],
    classes: ['kite-shape','double-sided'],
    content: 'Famo.us Kite',
    properties: {
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.05)',
      fontSize: '0.9em'
    }
  });
```

#### Considerations:

- You could put the kite shape inside your surface with your text content prior (example snippet #2)
- You could also use the `ImageSurface` and make a kite image to be used by the surface.

### Example code snippet below with a rotation effect, so you can play with it.

```js
define('main', function (require, exports, module) {
  var Engine = require('famous/core/Engine');
  var OptionsManager = require('famous/core/OptionsManager'); 
  var Surface = require('famous/core/Surface');
  var Modifier = require('famous/core/Modifier');
  var RenderNode = require('famous/core/RenderNode');
  var Transform = require('famous/core/Transform');
  var TransitionableTransform = require('famous/transitions/TransitionableTransform');

  var mainContext = Engine.createContext();
  mainContext.setPerspective(1000);

  var kite = new Surface({ 
    classes: ['kite-shape','double-sided'],
    content: 'Famo.us Kite',
    properties: {
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.05)',
      fontSize: '0.9em'
    }
  });

  var tt = new TransitionableTransform();
  mainContext.add(new Modifier({
    size: [100, 100],
    origin:[0.5, 0.5],
    align:[0.5, 0.5],
    transform: rotate
  })).add(kite);


  var initialTime = Date.now();
  
  function rotate() {
    var radians = 0.001 * (Date.now() - initialTime);
    tt.set(Transform.rotateAxis([0,1,0.25], Math.PI * radians));
    return tt.get();
  }
  
  });
require(['main']);
```

```html
<script src="http://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.1.16/minified/require.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.famo.us/lib/requestAnimationFrame.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.famo.us/lib/classList.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.famo.us/lib/functionPrototypeBind.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.famo.us/famous/0.3.5/famous.css" />

<script src="http://code.famo.us/famous/0.3.5/famous.min.js"></script>

<div class="kite-css">CSS</div>

<style>
.double-sided {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
  backface-visibility: visible;
}

.kite-css {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 50px solid red;
  top: -40px;
  position: relative;
}
.kite-css:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: -50px; 
  top: 50px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 50px solid transparent;
  border-top: 90px solid red;
  z-index: -1
}

.kite-shape {
  border: 50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 50px solid red;
  top: -40px;
}
.kite-shape:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: -50px; 
  top: 50px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 50px solid transparent;
  border-top: 90px solid red;
  z-index: -1
}
</style>
```

### Example code snippet #2.

Has the kite shape inside a surface.

```js
define('main', function (require, exports, module) {
  var Engine = require('famous/core/Engine');
  var OptionsManager = require('famous/core/OptionsManager'); 
  var Surface = require('famous/core/Surface');
  var Modifier = require('famous/core/Modifier');
  var RenderNode = require('famous/core/RenderNode');
  var Transform = require('famous/core/Transform');
  var TransitionableTransform = require('famous/transitions/TransitionableTransform');

  var mainContext = Engine.createContext();
  mainContext.setPerspective(1000);

  var kite = new Surface({ 
    size: [100, 300],
    classes: ['double-sided'],
    content: 'Famous Kite<div class="kite-css"></div>',
    properties: {
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.05)',
      fontSize: '0.9em',
      lineHeight: '12px'
    }
  });

  var tt = new TransitionableTransform();
  mainContext.add(new Modifier({
    size: [100, 100],
    origin:[0.5, 0.5],
    align:[0.5, 0.5],
    transform: rotate
  })).add(kite);

  var initialTime = Date.now();
  
  function rotate() {
    var radians = 0.001 * (Date.now() - initialTime);
    tt.set(Transform.rotateAxis([0,1,0.25], Math.PI * radians));
    return tt.get();
  }
  
  });
require(['main']);
```

```html
<script src="http://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.1.16/minified/require.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.famo.us/lib/requestAnimationFrame.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.famo.us/lib/classList.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.famo.us/lib/functionPrototypeBind.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.famo.us/famous/0.3.5/famous.css" />

<script src="http://code.famo.us/famous/0.3.5/famous.min.js"></script>

<div class="kite-css">CSS</div>

<style>
.double-sided {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
  backface-visibility: visible;
}

.kite-css {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 50px solid red;
  top: -40px;
  position: relative;
}
.kite-css:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: -50px; 
  top: 50px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 50px solid transparent;
  border-top: 90px solid red;
  z-index: -1
}

.kite-shape {
  border: 50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 50px solid red;
  top: -40px;
}
.kite-shape:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: -50px; 
  top: 50px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 50px solid transparent;
  border-top: 90px solid red;
  z-index: -1
}
</style>
```